# Element css causes hiding slider items in Flexslider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, flexslider

I am using about 10 flexsliders in a page. On loading of page all sliders will be hidden, and it will show on clicking of some element.

My problem is the slider is not working. I found an element css on slider `ul`

```
width: 2000%;
transition-duration: 0s;
transform: translate3d(-440px, 0px, 0px);
```

If I remove that `transform: translate3d(-440px, 0px, 0px);` , the slider works fine.

for calling slider am using the following code

```
 $("#p171 .slider").flexslider({
        animation:"slide",
        slideshow:false,
        directionNav:false,
        controlNav:true,
        animationSpeed:600
 });
```

Comment: what is the question here?

Comment: we need more informations.. what slider are you using or did you have created itself?

Comment: flexslider 1 or 2? any code or example of you problem?

Comment: when the div is hidden, the slider works.when its shown, slider not wroking. its adding some element css. Can i give live site link here???

Comment: What is the code you are using to show the div as flexslider wouldn't add those css values you are showing